# Memory game question (organizing the cards to 4x4+on click the game restarts)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a memory game. I'm almost done with it, but there are 2 parts that I need help with.
1. I can't figure out how to show my 16 cards in a 4x4 way. (probably something small, but hey i'm a noob)
2. I need a new game button, that resets the cards.

I have not really tried anything, I would like to get help and understand it while i'm implementing the fix.

```
  handleClick(name,index){
    if(this.state.openedFrameworks.length === 2){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.check()
      },750)
    }else {
      let framework = {
        name,
        index
      }
      let finalizedFrameworks = this.state.finalizedFrameworks
      let frameworks = this.state.openedFrameworks
      finalizedFrameworks[index].close = false
      frameworks.push(framework)
      this.setState({
        openedFrameworks: frameworks,
        finalizedFrameworks: finalizedFrameworks
      })
      if(this.state.openedFrameworks.length === 2){
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.check()
        },750)
      }
    }
  } 
  check(){
    let finalizedFrameworks = this.state.finalizedFrameworks
    if((this.state.openedFrameworks[0].name === this.state.openedFrameworks[1].name) && (this.state.openedFrameworks[0].index !== this.state.openedFrameworks[1].index)){
      finalizedFrameworks[this.state.openedFrameworks[0].index].complete = true
      finalizedFrameworks[this.state.openedFrameworks[1].index].complete = true
    }else {
      finalizedFrameworks[this.state.openedFrameworks[0].index].close = true
      finalizedFrameworks[this.state.openedFrameworks[1].index].close = true
    }
    this.setState({
      finalizedFrameworks,
      openedFrameworks: []
    })
  }
  start(){
    let finalizedFrameworks = [];
    this.state.duplicatedFrameworks = this.state.frameworks.concat(this.state.frameworks)
    this.state.randomizedFrameworks = this.shuffle(this.state.duplicatedFrameworks)
    this.state.randomizedFrameworks.map((name,index) => {
      finalizedFrameworks.push({
        name,
        close: true,
        complete: false,
        fail: false
      })
    })
    this.state.finalizedFrameworks = finalizedFrameworks
  }
  shuffle(array){
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array
  }
  render(){

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div className="game">
          {
            this.state.finalizedFrameworks.map((framework, index) => {           
              return <Card framework={framework.name} click={() => {this.handleClick(framework.name,index)}} close={framework.close} complete={framework.complete}/>
            })
          }
      </div>

      <button onClick={}>
            NEW GAME
      </button>
      </React.Fragment>

    )
  }
```

I expect the following:

1. The cards are in a 4x4 way.
2. New game button resets the cards.

Thx a lot!

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing right now?

Comment: use an external div, and define the Card div with 25% width... or use flexbox css

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo Thx the 25% fixed it!

Comment: @Hades Now I only need to add a New Game button.

Answer (score 0):

To restart, I think you just need to setState to the original starting state. Assuming your start() function is responsible to generate the initial state

```
  start(){
    let finalizedFrameworks = [];

    this.state.duplicatedFrameworks = this.state.frameworks.concat(this.state.frameworks)
    this.state.randomizedFrameworks = this.shuffle(this.state.duplicatedFrameworks)
    this.state.randomizedFrameworks.map((name,index) => {
      finalizedFrameworks.push({
        name,
        close: true,
        complete: false,
        fail: false
      })
    })


    // this.state.finalizedFrameworks = finalizedFrameworks

    // Instead of just setting the state directly, need to do setState to trigger re-render
    this.setState({finalizedFrameworks})
  }
```

Then your NEW GAME button just need to call start() function to restart

```
render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
      <div className="game">
          {
            this.state.finalizedFrameworks.map((framework, index) => {           
              return <Card framework={framework.name} click={() => {this.handleClick(framework.name,index)}} close={framework.close} complete={framework.complete}/>
            })
          }
      </div>

      <button onClick={() => this.start()}>
            NEW GAME
      </button>
      </React.Fragment>

    )
  }
```

Comment: Thx. I know It should work, it makes sense, but it did not. At the end I just refreshed the page, which restarted the memory game as well. :)

Comment: How did it not work? Game restarted, but at some random state? Or NEW GAME button not responding at all?